# Redirecting when listening to WebView Load events in Nativescript.

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have recently been developing my first web application with NativeScript and have been stuck on this for the last few days.

The application is built on Nativescript 3.2 with angular

My application is making a webview visible when a user clicks on a button and then listening to the finished load events. The code works as expected until I try to redirect to another page. I am not sure if it is getting in a redirect loop though the app just crashes.

```
webViewSetup() {
    let webview: WebView = this.webView.nativeElement;
    let navCount = 0; 

    webview.src = // Backend url

    webview.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, function (args: LoadEventData) {

        var res = args.url.substr(0,args.url.indexOf("?")); 

        if(res == // Success page url)
        {
            // Do something 

            if(navCount === 0 ){ // Crashes the application
                this.routerExtension.navigate(["home"],{clearHistory: true});
            }

        }

}


Auth(){
    this.isLoading = true; 
    this.webViewSetup(); 
}
```

I am hoping someone will be able to explain why the app is crashing or perhaps a better way to redirect to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. This is your code with the fix.

```
webview.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, function (args: LoadEventData) {

    var res = args.url.substr(0,args.url.indexOf("?")); 

    if(res == // Success page url)
    {
        // Do something 

        if(navCount === 0 ){ // Crashes the application
            this.routerExtension.navigate(["home"],{clearHistory: true});
        }

    }

}, this);
```

Please note the use of the **this** operator.